# Supplied parameter sid is in use

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to copy a user from my live server to my DR server using the following command:

```
CREATE LOGIN [xxx] 
WITH PASSWORD = 0x010006278DD83306AD19FA8B0CE4405F13DA83DDDFB25B088D7C HASHED
    , SID = 0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D
    , DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]
    , CHECK_POLICY = OFF
    , CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
```

I then get an error:

> Msg 15433, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Supplied parameter sid is in use.

So I check the sys.syslogins with:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE sid =  '0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D'
```

This finds nothing. So my question is what else could be using this sid?

Comment: take the quote marks off in your comparison `WHERE sid = 0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D`

Comment: ...also you should be using `sys.server_principals`, not `sys.syslogins` (deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@SteBov noted in his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161961/supplied-parameter-sid-is-in-use/161966#comment311460_161961), comparing the sid with quotes around it is problematic since that forces an implicit conversion to be performed against the sid column.  Since the conversion converts the hexadecimal value into a character value, you will never see the login in the query results.

If you check the execution plan for the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.sid = '0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D';
```

We see the following clustered index scan against the internal table, sys.sysxlgns:

[image]

In the details, you can see the following predicate:

> [master].[sys].[sysxlgns].[type] as [p].[type]<>'M' AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(85),[master].[sys].[sysxlgns].[sid] as [p].[sid],0)='0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D'

If you run a select changing the `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` into a simple `CONVERT` statement, as below, you can see the sid column is not what you'd expect:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(85), sp.sid, 0)
FROM sys.server_principals sp;
```

In order to successfully find the login with the duplicate sid, you'll need to run the select like:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.syslogins sl
WHERE sl.sid = 0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D;
```

Preferably, you'd look at `sys.server_principals` since [syslogins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a SQL Server 2000 compatible view that has been deprecated.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.sid = 0xFEEBD63ECD0F6A41AE60A6E0414F5A1D;
```

Comment: Removing the quotes was spot on. Found the user and was able to delete it.